# Extracting values from an array of Deferreds

Tags: jquery, arrays, deferred

I have an array of Deferred objects, which I'm trying to map to their resolved values once they complete.  I want to return the array when everything finishes resolving.

Here's what I have so far:

```
$.when.apply(null, deferredArray)
.pipe(function(){
  return deferredArray;
});
```

Unfortunately, this returns the array of Deferred objects in the resolved state.
Is there any way I can directly access the resolved elements?  I know I can chain `.then` and `.pipe` on the resolved array of Deferred objects individually, but this doesn't work well for my purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deferred objects are not designed to **return** any values. You have to handle the results in callbacks.

The results are passed as arguments to the `done`, `fail` or `pipe` callbacks:

```
$.when.apply(null, deferredArray).then(function(){
  // arguments[0] is the result of the first deferred object
  // arguments[1] is the result of the second deferred object
  // ...

  // or simple pass it to a function that needs the results:
  someFunction(arguments);
});
```

Of couse in you can also just set that function as callback:

```
$.when.apply(null, deferredArray).then(someFunction);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/RJ4RY/)

Comment: I understand, but as I mentioned, this doesn't work well for my purposes.  I'm using a JS library where I'm supposed to pass in a certain structure (array of objects).  I use AJAX calls to get the objects, so I need to pass the array of resolved values.

Comment: @JiaweiLi: As I said in my comment to your answer, even if you can get the array, at the moment it is processed, it might not contain any values yet. You have to call the library function inside the callback. See my update.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a hacky solution:

```
extractDeferredArray = function(array) {
  var deferred, extract, ret;
  ret = [];

  extract = (function() {
    var _i, _len, _results;
    _results = [];
    for (_i = 0, _len = array.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
      deferred = array[_i];
      _results.push(deferred.then(function(value) {
        return ret.push(value);
      }));
    }
    return _results;
  })();

  // Make sure our .then methods have completed
  return $.when.apply(null, extract).pipe(function() {
    return ret;
  });
};
```

Seems kind of awkward to have to do this.

Comment: How is CoffeeScript suppose to help here?

Comment: I generally find CoffeeScript easier to code in.  Changed my solution to Javascript in case people don't know it.

Comment: Oh, I did not even noticed that you answered your own question. I was just confused because you did not even mention CoffeeScript in your question. Anyways, your code might not work as expected. At the moment `extractDeferredArray` returns the array, it might not be populated yet because the deferred objects might not be resolved yet.

Comment: In my opening post, instead of `return deferredArray`, you'd use `return extractDeferredArray(deferredArray)`.  All the deferred objects are guaranteed to have resolved because of `$.when.apply(null, deferredArray)`.

Comment: Ok I see.... anyways, that's not necessary, `arguments` already contains the resolved values. You are making it too complicated.

Comment: What is `arguments`?  Do you mean `array`?  If so, that contains the Deferred objects, not the resolved values.

Comment: No. `arguments` is a special variable in each function that is an array-like object containing all arguments passed to the function. Have a look at my demo and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments.

Comment: Ah, I ended up having to convert the arguments object into an array via `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);`.  How did you know arguments contains the resolved Deferreds?  I didn't find anything referencing this in the official jQuery docs.

Comment: It's in the example of http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/, and yeah, sometimes it is necessary to convert `arguments` into a real array, like I also did in my demo.